# Как динамически выводить из input в какой то тег?

Tags: html, jquery

Как динамически выводить веденный текст в поле input в тег div.... с помощью jquery

К примеру есть поле

```
<input type="text" class="input-summa uk-input uk-form-width-small" name="summa" required pattern="^[ 0-9]+$" placeholder="Сумма" maxlength="6">
```

и вот сюда мне нужно выводить значение веденное в поле, но чтоб при этом происходили вычисление, к примеру веденное число разделить на 100, или умножить...

```
<span class="summa_one"></span>
```

А также, то что мы получим в теги span вывелось в таком вот поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="win">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[name='summa']").on("keyup, change", function(e){
  var val = +$(this).val() / 100;
  if (isNaN(val))
    val = "";
  $(".summa_one").text(val);
  $("input[name='win']").val(val);
});
```

Comment: не могли бы вы объяснить что да как?) пожалуйста)

Comment: @Евгений что Вам в данном коде непонятно?

Comment: Все-все... понятно, спасибо

Comment: @Евгений, советую кешировать элементы, с которыми будете работать многократно. А вместо двух событий `keyup` и `change`, можно использовать одно - `input`. Проверку `isNaN`, я бы делал до математических операций, сразу после приведение к числовому типу